# How to add rows and columns into datatable in single loop?

Tags: c#, json, datatable, dataset, datarow

I have Json stored in DataBase which I deserialize into DataTable with the help of **Newtonsoft.Json** like this

```
string jsonString = "[myJsonfromDB....]";
//Deserialize to DataTable
DataTable dtSerialized = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Which gives me result like this ***other columns in image are not shown***

[image]

Here my **label** is Column and **value** is column value. Both of these columns will be moved to new DataTable which I'll process further for my operations. Now my problem is that **I want to do it in one loop** while I do it in multiple loops i.e add columns first (in first loop) and then add column values (in second loop). Currently I'm doing it like this

```
string colName = string.Empty;
// First Loop to add columns
foreach (DataRow dr in dtSerialized.Rows)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Utility.Instance.ToString(dr["label"])))
   {
      colName = prefix + "_" + Utility.Instance.ToString(dr["label"]).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("/", "_").Replace("-", "_");
      if (!dtResult.Columns.Contains(colName))
      dtResult.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(string));
   }
}

DataRow drSelect = dtResult.NewRow();
//Second loop to add column values
foreach (DataRow dr in dtSerialized.Rows)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Utility.Instance.ToString(dr["label"])))
   {
      colName = prefix + "_" + Utility.Instance.ToString(dr["label"]).Replace(" ", "").Replace("/", "_").Replace("-", "_");
      drSelect[colName] = dr["value"];
   }
}

dtResult.Rows.Add(drSelect);
dsResult.Tables.Add(dtResult);
```

After this I have

[image]

As much I know is that first DataRow schema is built from DataTable and then values can be added which is clear in above code. Now, **How can i do it in one loop?** Or should I search for alternate method which i don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing I am missing something here. This looks like a transpose function and I cannot think of a way to accomplish this without two loops or transposing the data as you read it in. But going from what is posted it appears the column `label` holds the new `DataTable`’s column names. The first column is the first row of data to this new `DataTable`.

If this is the case then while you are looping through the rows to get the column names from column 1 (label), you can also get the “value’ from column 0 (value) and put this value in a `List<string>` named `valuesList` below.

Then after you have looped through all the rows and set the columns in the new `DataTable` `dtResults` you can add a single row from the `valuesList` by setting the list to a string array like below. This will produce the second picture you showed in one loop. Again I am guessing there is more to it than this simple transpose. Since a `DataTable` does not have a built in transpose function you will have to write your own. Not sure how you would do this in one loop though. Hope this helps.

```
private DataTable Transpose2ColDT(DataTable dtSource) {
  string prefix = "DIAP_";
  string colName = "";
  DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
  List<string> valuesList = new List<String>();
  if (dtSource.Rows.Count > 0) {
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtSource.Rows) {
      if (!dr.IsNull("Label")) {
        if (dr.ItemArray[1].ToString() != "" ) {
          colName = prefix + "_" + dr.ItemArray[1].ToString();
          if (!dtResult.Columns.Contains(colName)) {
            dtResult.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(string));
            valuesList.Add(dr.ItemArray[0].ToString());
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dtResult.Rows.Add(valuesList.ToArray<string>());
  } // no rows in the original source
  return dtResult;
}
```

Comment: You guessed it right @JohnG .. it is working with one loop and slight changes. Thanks